# Postgresql performance issue when querying on time range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to understand a strange performance issue on Postgres (v10.9).

We have a `requests` table and I want to get all requests made by a set of particular users in several time ranges. Here is the relevant info:

- There is no `user_id` column in the table. Rather, there is a jsonb column named `params`, where the `user_id` field is stored as a string.
- The set of users in question is very large, in the thousands.
- There is a `time` column of type timestamptz and it's indexed with a standard BTREE index.
- There is also an separate BTREE index on `params->>'user_id'`.

The queries I am running are based on the following template:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM requests
WHERE params->>'user_id' = ANY (VALUES ('id1'), ('id2'), ('id3')...)
AND time > 't1' AND time < 't2'
```

Where the ids and times here are placeholders for actual ids and times.

I am running a query like this for several consecutive time ranges of 2 weeks each. The queries for the first few time ranges take a couple of minutes each, which is obviously very long in terms of production but OK for research purposes. Then suddenly there is a dramatic spike in query runtime, and they start taking hours each, which begins to be untenable even for offline purposes.

This spike happens in the same range every time. It's worth noting that in this time range there is a x1.5 increase in total requests. Certainly more compared with the previous time range, but not enough to warrant a spike by a full order of magnitude.

Here is the output for `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the last time range with the reasonable running time:

```
Hash Join  (cost=442.69..446645.35 rows=986171 width=1217) (actual time=66.305..203593.238 rows=445175 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: ((requests.params ->> 'user_id'::text) = \"*VALUES*\".column1)
  ->  Index Scan using requests_time_idx on requests  (cost=0.56..428686.19 rows=1976888 width=1217) (actual time=14.336..201643.439 rows=2139604 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((\"time\" > '2019-02-12 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (\"time\" < '2019-02-26 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
  ->  Hash  (cost=439.62..439.62 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=43.818..43.818 rows=29175 loops=1)
        Buckets: 32768 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 2536kB
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=437.62..439.62 rows=200 width=32) (actual time=24.887..33.775 rows=29175 loops=1)
              Group Key: \"*VALUES*\".column1
              ->  Values Scan on \"*VALUES*\"  (cost=0.00..364.69 rows=29175 width=32) (actual time=0.006..10.303 rows=29175 loops=1)
Planning time: 133.807 ms
Execution time: 203697.360 ms
```

If I understand this correctly, it seems that most of the time is spent on filtering the requests by time range, even though:

- The time index seems to be used.
- When running the same queries without the filter on the users (basically just fetching all requests by time range only), they both run in OK times.

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving so many rows, the query will never be really fast.

Unfortunately there is no single index to cover both conditions, but you can use these two:

```
CREATE INDEX ON requests ((params->>'user_id'));
CREATE INDEX ON requests (time);
```

Then you can hope for two bitmap index scans which get joined by a “bitmap or”.

I am not sure if that will improve performance; PostgreSQL may still opt for the current plan, which is not a bad one. If your indexes are cached or random access to your storage is fast, set `effective_cache_size` or `random_page_cost` accordingly, that will make PostgreSQL lean towards an index scan.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We do have the indices you mentioned.

Comment: Then I don't think it can be improved.